# Casting the values from User input (Text Box) into String Array for port.write() to Arduino in Processing 3.0

Tags: arrays, interface, arduino, processing

I am working on Processing and arduino interface. Up to some extend, I was successful and Using Processing 3.0 as a user interface I was able to send commands to arduino. However, I was able to send only one value and arduino run a stepper motors with it on that particular simultaneously for all 3 motors.
However, I want to control all 3 motors with different speeds. For that I need to cast 3 different values from Processing to Arduino.
I intent to use an array and later split that array in arduino.

My code for processing is as below:

```
import controlP5.*;
import processing.serial.*; // when we add any value in GUI it will go the the arduino through serial
Serial port;
ControlP5 cp5;
PFont font; //for enlarging the font size
String textA;
String textB;
String textC;
String q;

void setup(){
  size(900,500); //(width,height)  
  
  printArray(Serial.list()); //prints all available Serial port
   //port = new Serial(this,"COM5",115200);
                                                                                    //lets add button to the window
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  font = createFont("Ebrima bold",20); // custom fonts for button and title
  
  cp5.addTextfield("Motor 1").setPosition(150,300).setSize(80,50).setAutoClear(false)
     .setFont(font)
     .setColorBackground(color(50, 113, 20));
     
     //Processing text input box
     //textbox1.draw();
    
  
  cp5.addTextfield("Motor 2") 
  .setPosition(450,300) 
       .setSize(80,50) 
       .setFont(font)
       .setColorBackground(color(50, 113, 20)); 
  
  cp5.addTextfield("Motor 3")
  .setPosition(750,300)
      .setSize(80,50) 
      .setFont(font)
      .setColorBackground(color(50, 113, 20));
          
   cp5.addBang("Submit").setPosition(450,400).setSize(100,50);
    
}

void draw(){
     background(10,100,80) ; //background colour (0 to 255) or (r,b,g)
       
      fill(250,55,0); //(text colour(r,g,b) 
        //Line 5
        fill(0,0,0); //(text colour(r,g,b)
       font = createFont("Ebrima",18);
       textFont(font);
        text(" Please Choose Stepper Motors Speed Below:",150,250);      
       
  }
void Submit () {
  textA=cp5.get(Textfield.class,"Motor 1").getText();
  textB=cp5.get(Textfield.class,"Motor 2").getText();
  textC=cp5.get(Textfield.class,"Motor 3").getText();
  
 q = textA+textB+textC;
 String[] data1 = textA;
String data = concat(textA,textB,textC); 
String data = join(data, ',') 

port.write(data);
}
```

However, I am unable to make an array from the user input which I could send to my serial port.

Need help on this, please.

Comment: With a little efforts from this tutorial https://pages.uoregon.edu/park/Processing/process4.html I am able to make a string of numbers. If anyone have an experience or any tutorial of reading the the string array in Arduino then please do share.
Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm an absolute newbie, but maybe here's how it's going to work:

```
String[] data1 = new String[3];
data1[0]=textA;
data1[1]=textB;
data1[2]=textC;
String data = join(data1, ',');
```

Comment: Thankyou Bill. I did modified my code like this from above tutorial but the joining of strings was different. So I will try this and let you know.